# Embedded Node.js + Express

Tags: linux, ajax, node.js, embedded

Имеется embedded linux девайс, на нем 64Mb оперативки, потребовали сделать веб морду с ajax,динамической отрисовкой страницы и прочее. Проблема в том, что qt приложение,для отображения,управления на экране прибора, занимает около 30 Mb оперативы и веб-сервер(node.js +express.js) около 35Mb.
Есть способ уменьшить объем оперативки для node.js?

Comment: Qt приложение для gui на экране устройства и оно же обрабатывает данные с него. Express.js

Comment: **добавльте, пожалуйста, эту информацию прямо в вопрос**. чтобы изменить текст вопроса, нажмите [edit] ниже текста вопроса.

Comment: Вероятно, можно переписать сервер на Go ¯\\_(ツ)_/¯

Comment: D-side, компилятор под arm926 найдешь?)

Comment: Не поверите! [Найду](http://dave.cheney.net/unofficial-arm-tarballs). Хотя и слегка устаревший, но и armv5 не нов.

Comment: Go компилятор под arm 2000 года?

Comment: Node.js вышел в 2009. Так, для справки.

Comment: @D-side И? Сервер работает спокойно на node, только оперативы много ест.

Comment: Ну, потому и вопрос, с чего бы не существовать компилятору Go для процессора 2000-ного года, если Node.js, только начавшийся в 2009, тоже на нём функционирует.

Comment: @D-side Ну потому что node собирается из исходников buildroot'ом. А собирать самому из исходников go под старый arm, уйдет слишком много времени